# Face lock using JavaScript without using any third-party frameworks including TensorFlow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, authentication, machine-learning, face-recognition

Whenever I'm working on any web project, I always want to develop everything on my own without using any third-party framewoks or libraries. I had actually designed password based authentication using sessions. Now I would like to implement face authentication. How can I do that?

**How can I train my JS detecting user face? What is the logic behind this? I don't want to use any third-party framewoks or libraries even from trusted companies. For instance, if a third-party JavaScript framework can help us in doing this, then why can't we do that? Even that framework is also coded in JavaScript right?**

Comment: Sure you can, but it will be a lot of work (orders of magnitude larger than just password based auth), for no real benefit, even worse if you are not a ML specialist.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in many ways, using C++ libraries, Tensorflow, Tensorflow Lite, Tensorflow JS, and authenticating process as your intention. Communication is a single point target with the response of information and targets. ( JS is simply https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/ )

Face recognition is easy you can do it without API but with API they can adjust easily and have those parameters interfaces. I simply an example this codes many times but it is working when the face recognition is possible with Tensorflow and Python. The exchange parameters are only authentication and your camera access with return some parameter told you to do next process or with messages errors return.

Comment: But I want to do that only with JavaScript.

Comment: I replied it is possible when you find a matching of requirements and program you to need the application to running TensorFlow but you need web form to display Javascript I am doing now with adding JS to ASP.net but the same idea should work.

Comment: Sorry! Actually I don't know ASP.net

Comment: I build some programs and test it when I do it on Windows with .NET 4.6.2 that is because I will need both Tensorflow and web application.